# Is there a way to generate JavaDoc from within Domino Designer?

Tags: xpages

I export my Domino Designer Java code to Eclipse in order to generate JavaDoc but this is cumbersome.

I have tried on several occasions to do the same thing from inside DDE but the process fails and have not found a solution.

Is there a way to generate JavaDoc for managed beans from DDE?

Answer (score 3):

JavaDoc is available as an ANT task. Domino Designer can run ANT tasks manually or as part of the build process. Only catch: ANT doesn't know the Eclipse Virtual File system. You have 2 options to overcome this:
Use the version control connection - this copies all files into a directory - or use the Import/Export plug-in from OpenNTF. It has an ANT interface.

Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks.  Will check out those options.

Comment: For how to set it up as an ANT task, I recommend Paul Withers's blog post:
http://www.intec.co.uk/generating-javadocs-for-xpages-applications/