# How to generate a javadoc in XPages

Tags: xpages

When I try to generate a javadoc, using the menu command Project\Generate Javadoc, the following warnings and error are produced for my custom classes in XPages:

```
javadoc: warning - No source files for package net.focul.utilties
javadoc: warning - No source files for package net.focul.workflow
javadoc: error - No public or protected classes found to document.
```

The packages are in the `WebContent/WEB-INF/src` folder which is configured in the build path and are selectable in the Generate Javadoc wizard. The classes are public with public methods.

Javadocs are generated for all of the Xpage and Custom Control classes if I select these.

Comment: Possible duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144503/is-there-a-way-to-generate-javadoc-from-within-domino-designer

Answer (score 1):

You're experiencing this behavior because javadoc doesn't understand the Designer VFS (Virtual File System). It assumes that your project consists of a bunch of separate files in some folder structure on your local hard drive, not self-contained inside a single NSF. On the whole, the Designer VFS successfully tricks Eclipse into believing it's interacting with local files by intercepting read/write requests for project resources and importing/exporting DXL or CD records, etc. But apparently they haven't applied this sleight of hand to javadoc as well.

The Java source files corresponding to each XPage and Custom Control are processed successfully because, ironically, they are never stored in the NSF. During every project build, Designer discards any of these it has already generated and re-creates them based on the current contents of the various .xsp files. It then compiles those Java files into .class files, which *are* stored as design notes inside the NSF. At runtime, it's these files that are extracted from the VFS and executed... the source code no longer matters at this point, so there's no reason to ever bother including the .java files in the NSF, so they're just kept on the hard drive. One indication of this behavior is that the folder is named "Local" when viewed in Package Explorer / Navigator.

If you're using the built in (as of 8.5.3) version control integration (see [this article](http://www.keithstric.com/A55BAC/keithstric.nsf/default.xsp?documentId=B236F39DEAF6C52F85257A72001157BF) for a great explanation of how to use this feature), you can tweak the Build Path to include the copy of the src folder stored in the on-disk project as a "linked source folder". This causes javadoc to consider the duplicate copies valid source files, and therefore includes them in the generated documentation. On the downside, it also causes Designer to consider them valid source files, which causes compilation errors due to the duplication. So this approach is only viable if you only need to generate the documentation on an infrequent basis, and can therefore break the Build Path temporarily just to run javadoc, then revert to the usual settings.

An alternative is to actually maintain your custom Java code this way on an ongoing basis: instead of creating the folder in WEB-INF inside the NSF, just create a folder on your hard drive that stores the source, then include that location as a linked source folder indefinitely. That way Designer can still find the source, but so can javadoc. **NOTE:** if you go this route, then you definitely need to use SCM. Because your source code no longer lives inside the NSF, providing the convenient container we're used to for getting the source code to other developers and ensuring inclusion in whatever backup schedule you use, the ***only*** place your source code now lives is on your local hard drive. So make sure you're regularly committing those files to Git / Subversion / Mercurial, etc., or, at the very least, storing them on some file server that is backed up regularly and, if applicable, accessible to all other members of the project team.

Answer (score 0):

When you expand the net.focul.utilties in Designer, you will see all the methods and properties. But when you click on on of the methods, you will see neo source code. 
So this is where javadoc fails to generate the documentation. I guess that the author of the application has not provided you with the source code. If you have the source somewhere, you can attach this code and then javadoc will be able to generate the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same situation and I have found the most straightforward method is to export the source to an external folder and then use regular Eclipse to generate the JavaDoc.  Not sure my process is any less of a hassle than Tim's suggestions but for me it just feels less risky than trying to deal with the VFS vagaries.

Comment: I find it easiest to stay in Designer. Just copy-paste the packages to a Java project and generate Javadoc from there. The location of javadoc.exe need to be entered in "Javadoc command" field.